# ASCII Art in CMD/MS-DOS

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

*ANSCII means "ASCII/ANSI"*
*Sorry about being off topic, admins - What Stack Exchange Site should I go to for these Questions?*

I've looked everywhere on Google for a Batch/Powershell ANSCII art Generator, and I can't find anything to do this job for me, and it is VERY hard to make ANSCII art. And I'm not just using *pre-defined ANSCII Art*, but User/Variable defined. Like this:

```
C:\> set var = "ANSI Test"
C:\> ansi %var%
 █████╗ ███╗   ██╗███████╗██╗    ████████╗███████╗███████╗████████╗
██╔══██╗████╗  ██║██╔════╝██║    ╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝
███████║██╔██╗ ██║███████╗██║       ██║   █████╗  ███████╗   ██║   
██╔══██║██║╚██╗██║╚════██║██║       ██║   ██╔══╝  ╚════██║   ██║   
██║  ██║██║ ╚████║███████║██║       ██║   ███████╗███████║   ██║   
╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝╚═╝       ╚═╝   ╚══════╝╚══════╝   ╚═╝
```

or

```
PS $var = "ANSI Test"
PS ansi $var
 █████╗ ███╗   ██╗███████╗██╗    ████████╗███████╗███████╗████████╗
██╔══██╗████╗  ██║██╔════╝██║    ╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝
███████║██╔██╗ ██║███████╗██║       ██║   █████╗  ███████╗   ██║   
██╔══██║██║╚██╗██║╚════██║██║       ██║   ██╔══╝  ╚════██║   ██║   
██║  ██║██║ ╚████║███████║██║       ██║   ███████╗███████║   ██║   
╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝╚═╝       ╚═╝   ╚══════╝╚══════╝   ╚═╝
```

or

```
C:\> set var = "ASCII Test"
C:\> ascii %var%
   db    .dP"Y8  dP""b8 88 88     888888 888888 .dP"Y8 888888 
  dPYb   `Ybo." dP   `" 88 88       88   88__   `Ybo."   88   
 dP__Yb  o.`Y8b Yb      88 88       88   88""   o.`Y8b   88   
dP""""Yb 8bodP'  YboodP 88 88       88   888888 8bodP'   88
```

or

```
PS $var = "ASCII Test"
PS ascii $var
   db    .dP"Y8  dP""b8 88 88     888888 888888 .dP"Y8 888888 
  dPYb   `Ybo." dP   `" 88 88       88   88__   `Ybo."   88   
 dP__Yb  o.`Y8b Yb      88 88       88   88""   o.`Y8b   88   
dP""""Yb 8bodP'  YboodP 88 88       88   888888 8bodP'   88
```

Comment: Check out http://www.figlet.org/. It's a C program but it should run on Windows and it has a DOS-specific font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote a program called FIGBat.bat that may use the fonts created for [FIGlet program](http://www.jave.de/figlet/fonts.html). For example, the following Batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
call figbat /f Banner My program
call figbat /f Doom use standard
call figbat /f Epic FigLet
call figbat /f Isometric1 FONTS
echo/
echo ______________________________________________________________________
echo/
call figbat /f Script Antonio
```

Create this output:

```
 #     #                                                                    
 ##   ##  #   #      #####   #####    ####    ####   #####     ##    #    # 
 # # # #   # #       #    #  #    #  #    #  #    #  #    #   #  #   ##  ## 
 #  #  #    #        #    #  #    #  #    #  #       #    #  #    #  # ## # 
 #     #    #        #####   #####   #    #  #  ###  #####   ######  #    # 
 #     #    #        #       #   #   #    #  #    #  #   #   #    #  #    # 
 #     #    #        #       #    #   ####    ####   #    #  #    #  #    # 

                         _                      _                   _ 
                        | |                    | |                 | |
 _   _  ___   ___   ___ | |_   __ _  _ __    __| |  __ _  _ __   __| |
| | | |/ __| / _ \ / __|| __| / _` || '_ \  / _` | / _` || '__| / _` |
| |_| |\__ \|  __/ \__ \| |_ | (_| || | | || (_| || (_| || |   | (_| |
 \__,_||___/ \___| |___/ \__| \__,_||_| |_| \__,_| \__,_||_|    \__,_|


 _______ _________ _______  _        _______ _________
(  ____ \\__   __/(  ____ \( \      (  ____ \\__   __/
| (    \/   ) (   | (    \/| (      | (    \/   ) (   
| (__       | |   | |      | |      | (__       | |   
|  __)      | |   | | ____ | |      |  __)      | |   
| (         | |   | | \_  )| |      | (         | |   
| )      ___) (___| (___) || (____/\| (____/\   | |   
|/       \_______/(_______)(_______/(_______/   )_(   

      ___           ___           ___           ___           ___     
     /\  \         /\  \         /\__\         /\  \         /\  \    
    /::\  \       /::\  \       /::|  |        \:\  \       /::\  \   
   /:/\:\  \     /:/\:\  \     /:|:|  |         \:\  \     /:/\ \  \  
  /::\~\:\  \   /:/  \:\  \   /:/|:|  |__       /::\  \   _\:\~\ \  \ 
 /:/\:\ \:\__\ /:/__/ \:\__\ /:/ |:| /\__\     /:/\:\__\ /\ \:\ \ \__\
 \/__\:\ \/__/ \:\  \ /:/  / \/__|:|/:/  /    /:/  \/__/ \:\ \:\ \/__/
      \:\__\    \:\  /:/  /      |:/:/  /    /:/  /       \:\ \:\__\  
       \/__/     \:\/:/  /       |::/  /     \/__/         \:\/:/  /  
                  \::/  /        /:/  /                     \::/  /   
                   \/__/         \/__/                       \/__/    

______________________________________________________________________

   ___,                                   
  /   |                           o       
 |    |   _  _   _|_  __   _  _       __  
 |    |  / |/ |   |  /  \_/ |/ |  |  /  \_
  \__/\_/  |  |_/ |_/\__/   |  |_/|_/\__/
```

The default font use Ansi block character:

```
C:\> figbat Ansi Test
    █                     █      ███████                   █
   █ █                              █                      █
  █   █   ████    ████   ██         █      ████    ████   ████
 █     █  █   █  █        █         █     █    █  █        █
 ███████  █   █   ████    █         █     █████    ████    █
 █     █  █   █       █   █         █     █            █   █
 █     █  █   █   ████    █         █      ████    ████     ██
```

You may copy FIGBat.bat program from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174465/how-would-i-use-some-multi-line-ascii-art-as-my-characters-for-a-counter-batch/19188162#19188162).