# How to store ASCII Art into a variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ascii-art

So I'm trying to create a simple ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS game wherein I want to display ASCII artwork for the individual elements. It would be great if I could store them into variables in some way for the further logic to follow up & use those variables.

```
   ....
   .....
     .......
      ........
         ........
            ........
               ........           .........
                 ..................       ..
                   ................       ..
                     .........   ....  ....
                      ..     ....
                      ..        ...
                       ...         ...
                       ...         ..
                          ...........
```

This is the piece of art & when I try to store it into a variable like:

```
set /p scissors = " the above art "
```

I get errors.

Does someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Which Windows version is this meant to run on?

Comment: Here's an idea, call your game R-P-S, and guess what, you can output the options much easier, `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C RPS`. Or if you really wanted to use representaions instead of alphabet letters, `@ _ X` each of which would take up the same mimimal amount of space.

Comment: `set /P` is for prompting the user for a value, and `set /P VAR = …` will not set `VAR` but `VAR`+ _space_. Anyway, do you really need the text in a variable? Take a look at this post for alternatives: [Windows batch: Can't echo ASCII art with ._|_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855559)…

Comment: This line: `set /p scissors = " the above art "` say nothing to us about your code. What do you put in the `set /p` command line? _The first line_ of the "above art"? And the rest of the lines below? If so, then it should be obvious why do you get errors...

Answer (score 3):

Another of may ways to approach the goal is to use findstr to read data embedded in your file. The findstr command may be assigned to a variable allowing it to be used repeatedly for different elements:

```bat
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 Mode 1000
 Set "Scissors="
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "RPS=For /f "tokens=2 Delims=RPS123" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /bl ":RPS#" "%~f0"')Do Echo(%%G"
 Choice /C:RPS
 %RPS:#=!Errorlevel!%

:RPS1             
:RPS1                
:RPS1                .. ... .. .. . 
:RPS1            . ... ... .. . .. .
:RPS1          . .. .  ... ... ......
:RPS1         .........   ..... ......
:RPS1        . ......   ..... ........ .
:RPS1         .........   ..... ......
:RPS1        .. ..  ................ .        
:RPS1          .. .....  .. .. .......
:RPS1            . . . ... . .. ... .
:RPS1             . ... .. . . . .
:RPS1              ...   ...   ..
:RPS1       
:RPS1          


:RPS2      . 
:RPS2     .  .
:RPS2    .     .
:RPS2   .        .
:RPS2  .           .
:RPS2 .              .
:RPS2.                 .
:RPS2  .                 .
:RPS2    .                 . 
:RPS2      .              .
:RPS2        .           .
:RPS2          .        .
:RPS2            .     .
:RPS2              .  .
:RPS2                .

:RPS3  ....
:RPS3   .....
:RPS3     .......
:RPS3      ........
:RPS3         ........
:RPS3            ........
:RPS3               ........           .........
:RPS3                 ..................       ..
:RPS3                   ................       ..
:RPS3                     .........   ....  ....
:RPS3                      ..     ....
:RPS3                      ..        ...
:RPS3                       ...         ...
:RPS3                       ...         ..
:RPS3                          ...........
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define your variable like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set Scissors=^

....^

  .....^

    .......^

      ........^

         ........^

            ........^

               ........           .........^

                 ..................       ..^

                   ................       ..^

                     .........   ....  ....^

                      ..     ....^

                      ..        ...^

                       ...         ...^

                       ...         ..^

                          ...........
```

Then to use it you could enable delayed expansion.

```sh
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(!Scissors!
```

Then later, revert to the previous delayed expansion state:

```sh
EndLocal
```

If you did not want to enable delayed expansion, it would take a little more work to output your image:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Scissors) 2>NUL"') Do Echo(%%G
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Define variables:

(for %%a in (
"      .. ... .. .. ."
"    . ... ... .. . .. ."
"  . .. .  ... ... ......"
" .........   ..... ......"
". ......   ..... ........ ."
" .........   ..... ......"
".. ..  ................ ."
"  .. .....  .. .. ......."
"    . . . ... . .. ... ."
"     . ... .. . . . ."
"      ...   ...   ..") do set "rock=!rock!$%%~a") & set "rock=!rock:~1!"

(for %%a in (
"      ."
"     .  ."
"    .     ."
"   .        ."
"  .           ."
" .              ."
".                 ."
"  .                 ."
"    .                 ."
"      .              ."
"        .           ."
"          .        ."
"            .     ."
"              .  ."
"                .") do set "paper=!paper!$%%~a") & set "paper=!paper:~1!"

(for %%a in (
"...."
" ....."
"   ......."
"    ........"
"       ........"
"          ........"
"             ........           ........."
"               ..................       .."
"                 ................       .."
"                   .........   ....  ...."
"                    ..     ...."
"                    ..        ..."
"                     ...         ..."
"                     ...         .."
"                        ...........") do set "scissors=!scissors!$%%~a") & set "scissors=!scissors:~1!"

REM Display variables:

cls

echo rock: & echo/& echo %rock:$=& echo %& echo/& echo/

echo paper: & echo/& echo %paper:$=& echo %& echo/& echo/

echo scissors: & echo/& echo %scissors:$=& echo %& echo/& echo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just putting an option out there, if you are running Windows 10, which supports VT100 escape codes, you can do something like:

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "n=%%iE"
set "scissors=%n%   ....%n%   .....%n%     .......%n%      ........%n%         ........%n%            ........%n%               ........           .........%n%                 ..................       ..%n%                   ................       ..%n%                     .........   ....  ....%n%                      ..     ....%n%                      ..        ...%n%                       ...         ...%n%                       ...         ..%n%                          ..........."
echo %scissors%
```

Comment: You are missing the `[` charcter in the Linefeed control sequence. `for /F %%i in ('echo(prompt $E^|cmd') do set "n=%%i[E"`

Comment: @T3RR0R not relevant here, test it for yourself. :)

Comment: I already had, and it fails as you've scripted it, it fails in cmd.exe and powershell.exe - It does however output correctly in windows terminal.

Comment: conversely, the reverse is true of `ESC[E`, it outputs correctly in Cmd.exe and powershell, but not in windows terminal unless explicitly in a cmd tab

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running, @T3RR0R?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348]

Comment: I am running `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.318]` i.e Windows 11. . here is [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDshu.png) it works as is for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240207/discussion-between-t3rr0r-and-gerhard).